# stdbuf supposed behavior for subprocesses

Tags: stdout, buffer, ld

I didn't exactly find something about the following in the [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf). How is the supposed behavior in subprocesses spawned by a process which was itself spawned by [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf)?

E.g.:

```
stdbuf -oL myprog
```

From the [code](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/stdbuf.c), I get that it sets [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), and as far as I know, all environment variables are inherited in any subprocesses.

I'm interested in both `fork();` and `fork(); execv();` subprocesses. (Not sure if that would make a difference.)

`fork();` should not change the behavior at all. `execv()` would use the same `LD_PRELOAD` (as well as the stdbuf settings which also stored in env) and thus apply the same behavior (from the example: stdout is line-buffered).

Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strace`ing the `execve` (with environ) and `write` system calls can help see what's going on:

Here with the `stdbuf` of GNU coreutils 8.25. I beleive FreeBSD's `stdbuf` works similarly:

#### exec and no fork:

```
$ env -i strace -s200 -vfe execve,write /usr/bin/stdbuf -o0 /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/env > /dev/null
execve("/usr/bin/stdbuf", ["/usr/bin/stdbuf", "-o0", "/usr/bin/env", "/usr/bin/env"], []) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["/usr/bin/env", "/usr/bin/env"], ["_STDBUF_O=0", "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so"]) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["/usr/bin/env"], ["_STDBUF_O=0", "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so"]) = 0
write(1, "_STDBUF_O=0\n", 12)           = 12
write(1, "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so\n", 60) = 60
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`LD_PRELOAD` and the config in `_STDBUF_O` is passed to both `env` commands. The two `write()` system calls even though the output doesn't go to a terminal confirms the output is not buffered.

#### fork and exec:

```
$ env -i strace -s200 -vfe execve,write /usr/bin/stdbuf -o0 /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/env; :' > /dev/null
execve("/usr/bin/stdbuf", ["/usr/bin/stdbuf", "-o0", "/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/env; :"], []) = 0
execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/env; :"], ["_STDBUF_O=0", "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so"]) = 0
Process 16809 attached
[pid 16809] execve("/usr/bin/env", ["/usr/bin/env"], ["_STDBUF_O=0", "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so", "PWD=/home/stephane"]) = 0
[pid 16809] write(1, "_STDBUF_O=0\n", 12) = 12
[pid 16809] write(1, "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so\n", 60) = 60
[pid 16809] write(1, "PWD=/home/stephane\n", 19) = 19
[pid 16809] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED,
```

Same situation.

So yes `stdbuf` applies to the command it runs and all of its descendants (provided they don't clean their environment like the dynamic linker or libc do with `LD_PRELOAD` for setuid/setgid... applications).

Comment: I was also interested in fork and no exec. But I guess that is very much straight-forward as it really should inherit everything, i.e. also same behavior.

Comment: It's not libc but the dynamic linker which clears `LD_PRELOAD` & co from the environment for setuid binaries.

Comment: @mosvy, well, at least on GNU systems, the dynamic linker comes from the same source as the libc and for statically linked applications, the libc does unset those same variables (in `libc.a:_dl_non_dynamic_init()`).

Comment: Yes, on GNU systems, glibc and rtld are part of the same software package, but they're still separate binaries. And they're completely different on other systems like BSD or Android. But an implementation where some constructor function pushed by libc would clear those envvars, while dumb, is perfectly imaginable -- does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

The buffering is inherited through the fork/exec of `timeout` as illustrated by the following test code:

```
bash-4.1$ cat isbuffed.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("should not appear if buffered");
    sleep(999);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
bash-4.1$ make isbuffed
cc     isbuffed.c   -o isbuffed
bash-4.1$ timeout 3 ./isbuffed
bash-4.1$ stdbuf -o0 timeout 3 ./isbuffed
should not appear if bufferedbash-4.1$
```