# non-blocking/multi-threaded cat

Tags: stdout, buffer

[`cat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) is blocking from what I see in the [code](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c), i.e. it uses blocking `read()` and then it uses blocking `write()`.

I want to call some tool where I disable all stdout buffering by purpose (e.g. like described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279984/stdbuf-supposed-behavior-for-subprocesses)), because that tool might call subprocesses and I want that all writings from all subprocesses on stdout will occur at the same time when they are written at the same time.

Then, I want to pipe that stdout into a multi-threaded version of `cat` (or so). The purpose is that the real stdout will be slow (it's a file on disk) but I don't want the tool to hang when it tries to write on stdout. If I would just do

```
stdbuf -oL mytool
```

then it would hang when the disk is busy or so.
When I do

```
stdbuf -oL mytool | cat
```

I'm actually not perfectly sure what will happen. I might get some additional buffering by the [kernel pipe buffer](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/), although I think that will not be used when I disable the stdout buffering of `mytool`. And then the stdout of `cat` will also be buffered by default, but at the time when `cat` really writes out its stdout, it might hang. `mytool` will hang when it writes something and `cat` is not reading at the same time.

That is why I'm searching for a multi-threaded `cat` which reads at the same time when it writes, so writing to the stdin of `multi-threaded-cat` will never be blocking (or only soft-blocking or whatever you would call that). It basically introduces another buffer in user-space in `multi-threaded-cat`. When `multi-threaded-cat` hangs while trying to write to stdout, it does not matter because it will still read from stdin in parallel.
So I want to do:

```
stdbuf -oL mytool | multi-threaded-cat
```

I want that `multi-threaded-cat` consumes the incoming data always as soon as possible. That is why I think that it probably should be multi-threaded. Otherwise, if it uses write(), that might block or at least give a small hickup and in the mean-while, it cannot read() from stdin.

I also want that `multi-threaded-cat` writes out the data as soon as possible. So it should not first fill its own buffer and then write, I want that it writes always immediately.

My use case is this: mytool, including some subprocesses, will write some logging information on stdout. `stdbuf` is important so that I don't get any delay in the output and also that all subprocesses stdouts are synced. All the stdout will be redirected to a log file on a fileserver which is a bit slow and it will greatly reduce the performance when it would wait for all writes to complete. So that is why I want something like `multi-threaded-cat` in between.

Is there such a tool?

I just implemented my own such tool [here](https://github.com/albertz/system-tools/blob/master/bin/mt-cat.py). Using this already gives me a speedup of 800%, compared to not using it. But maybe there are other tools or other ways to do what I want?

Comment: This might be way off-topic, but sounds you're looking for an asynchronous cat - which might be achieved with gnu's parallel - http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ and the man and tutorials: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html , http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html , https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 . Specifically you might be interested in --pipepart (With or without --cat)

Answer (score 3):

“Multi-threaded” is an implementation detail and not what you actually need: a multithreaded `cat` implementation could still block with one thread waiting for the other thread because it's waiting to have somewhere to put the data that it's read. What you're looking for is a **non-blocking** `cat`, with a potentially unbounded buffer.

The `sponge` utility from [Joey Hess's moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is an extreme version of this: it first reads the whole file into memory, then writes the output. This may or may not work for you.

[`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) lets you specify a buffer size. You can't have an unbounded buffer, but you can set a very large maximum size (make it as large as your memory if you like), the buffer is only allocated on demand.

```
stdbuf -oL mytool | pv -q -B 1g >output-file
```

Comment: What I meant which multi-threaded is that you can easily avoid the blocking write() issue with multi-threading. Have you looked at the code of my small tool? It does that in a very straight forward way. The buffer is also unbound and only there on demand (i.e. only when the write() is not fast enough).

Comment: About pv: From the documentation, I don't see that pv would use write() in parallel to read(). So while it is calling write(), it is not calling read() at the same time. If the write() is hanging for whatever reason, at this time, no more data can arrive. That is exactly what I want to avoid. The tool should always consume all incoming data as soon as possible.

Comment: About sponge: That is also not what I want. I want that it also writes the data as soon as possible out.

Comment: @Albert `pv` calls `select`, so it won't block unless there's a hardware failure.

Comment: But still write() can take some time to complete, and meanwhile, it will not call read().

Comment: Also, I just checked the source code of pv, and it will actually wait a short while when stdout is busy. While it waits, it will not call read().